# Why do my links not work in a i element?

Tags: html, hyperlink, font-awesome

Why doesn't my links work?

```
<section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Let's Get In Touch!</h2>
                    <hr class="primary">
                    <p>Ready to turn your idea into reality? Let's work together! Send me an email or give me a ring, and I will get back to you as soon as possible!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <a href="mailto:erichoonpark@gmail.com"><i id="contact" class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay=".1s"></i></a>
                    <p>Email</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/eric-park/30/19a/778"><i id="contact" class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-3x wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay=".1s"></i></a>
                    <p>LinkedIn</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <a href="tel://+12135981088"><i id="contact" class="fa fa-phone fa-3x wow bounceIn"></i></a>
                    <p>213-598-1088</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I have this section in github pages to contact me, but when I click on the icon... I recieve a 404 error. What is wrong with my html?

Comment: Your i tags are empty...

Comment: @Fasoeu - He's (presumably) using FontAwesome.

Comment: Works fine for me http://www.bootply.com/Q2kypR4cMa

Comment: I presume you have JavaScript or Css option disabling something because that code works ok. Do you have JS to post?

Answer (score 0):

As Fasoeu stated: you need to put the text, which then appears as the link, between the <a> tags! Not below!

```
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Let's Get In Touch!</h2>
        <hr class="primary">
        <p>Ready to turn your idea into reality? Let's work together! Send me an email or give me a ring, and I will get back to you as soon as possible!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <a href="mailto:erichoonpark@gmail.com"><i id="contact" class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay=".1s">Email</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/eric-park/30/19a/778"><i id="contact" class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-3x wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay=".1s">LinkedIn</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <a href="tel://+12135981088"><i id="contact" class="fa fa-phone fa-3x wow bounceIn">213-598-1088</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And if you intend to make the link-text appear italic, I suggest you use CSS to accomplish that! Like this:

```
<a href="example.com" style="font-style: italic;">link-text</a>
```

Or even better:

HTML:

```
<a href="example.com" class="italic">link-text</a>
```

CSS:

```
.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Now every element of the class "italic" will have italic font.